# Problems with articles

Tags: articles

Could anyone please explain me why the author of the book that I'm reading used the definite article in the following figure:

> "Figure 2.2. The population of the module.exports property or the exports object allows a module to select what should be shared with the application."

I'm interested in the part *"with the application"* because there was no previous mention of this application in the book.

Comment: It's an assumption without context, but when you use this bit of Node/JavaScript, presumably it will be as part of writing a specific application... it is to that application the book is referring. I.e. "_...the application you are writing_".

Comment: What is the problem with 'the'? Isn't that's just _the_ (or _any_ or _the calling_) application that is calling the module?

Comment: @TripeHound Does it sound better to you if this part would be written with an indefinite article: "with an application"? What sense does it convey in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: "_An_" could be used, but I think "_the_" sounds better, Although a module can be used in many different applications, _very often_ it is a single, _specific_ application that is being thought of at a time (especially if this bit of the book is talking about how to use modules to help write an application, and more especially if there is a specific application being built). If you were documenting a module (not teaching someone how to write one), _then_ it might make more sense to talk of sharing with an application (but I might still go with "_the calling (or main) application_").

Comment: @TripeHound Can you please also explain why in this sentence the indefinite article is used: "Over the course of the preceding section, you added a database module, created a JavaScript API that wraps around it, and         tied it in to the RESTful HTTP API." I'm intersted in the following part: "a database module, a Javascript API". Why "a", and not "the"?

Comment: I mean there was only one database module but the author used "a". Why? Please help me